# Wp query pagination and categories

Tags: wordpress, pagination, categories, archive

I'm new to Wp and I'm trying to developing my first theme. After I add the paginations to my archive page the category filter doesn't work anymore (probably because I override the WP Query).

What shoud I put in the query in order to see only the posts of the category that is clicked? (if I don't put anything wp do the magic) but without the query the pagination doesn't work.

This is the archive.php

```
<?php
    get_header(); ?>

    <?php
    if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <header class="page-header no-image">
            <?php
                the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title u-text-center">', '</h1>' );
            ?>
        </header><!-- .page-header -->

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/filter-category' ); ?>

        <?php
         /*QUERY:
         This is the problem if I move the query from there the category works but 
         If I leave the query the pagination doesn't have the post_per_page argument to take and doesn't work...
         */
          $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
          $args = array(
            'post_type'=>'post',
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 6,
            'paged' => $paged
          );
          $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
         /*END QUERY*/
        ?>

        <div id="blogpost-list" class="container">
          <div class="row blogpost-wrapper">
            <?php
            /* Start the Loop */
            $i = 1;
            while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
              <?php if ($i % 3 == 0): ?>
                <div class="blogpost-item-grid">
                    <!-- some stuff to display the post.. doesn't really matter-->
                  <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-post-preview-large' ); ?>
                </div>
              <?php else: ?>
                <div class="blogpost-item-grid">
                    <!-- some stuff to display the post doesn't really matter -->
                  <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-post-preview' ); ?>
                </div>
              <?php endif; ?>
              <?php $i++; ?>
            <?php endwhile;?>
          </div>
        </div>

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/pagination' ); ?>

        <?php
        else :
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
        endif; ?>

<?php
get_footer();
```

Here the code that I use for the pagination:

```
<?php //Require a wp->query ?>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="pagination-wrapper">
    <?php
    $pag_args = array(
        'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
        'total'        => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
        'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
        'show_all'     => false,
        'type'         => 'plain',
        'end_size'     => 2,
        'mid_size'     => 1,
        'prev_next'    => true,
        'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<img class="icn icn-small" src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/images/icn-chevron-left.svg"/>'),
        'next_text'    => sprintf( '<img class="icn icn-small" src="' . get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/images/icn-chevron-right.svg"/>'),
        'add_args'     => false,
        'add_fragment' => '',
    );
    echo paginate_links($pag_args);
    ?>

</div>
</div>
```

SOLVED: 
Add this to get the category

```
get_header();
$catID = get_queried_object_id();
```

Pass that to the query:

```
    $args = array(
      [...]
      'cat' => $catID
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Can you also share the code for the category template part?

Comment: Sure thanks, I updated the post

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using your **$wp_query** variable after its instanciation.
Your **while loop** should look like this:

```
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
   /*Your inner code here*/
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Thanks, now the pagination it's working but I'm still see all the post and not only the one in that category. Shoud I pass the category in the query?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the  category.php  file if it' not exists. Then Inside your file

```
<?php
    get_header();
   $catID = get_queried_object_id();

 ?>

    <?php
    if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <header class="page-header no-image">
            <?php
                the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title u-text-center">', '</h1>' );
            ?>
        </header><!-- .page-header -->

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/filter-category' ); ?>

        <?php
         /*QUERY:
         This is the problem if I move the query from there the category works but 
         If I leave the query the pagination doesn't have the post_per_page argument to take and doesn't work...
         */
          $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
          $args = array(
            'post_type'=>'post',
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 6,
            'cat' => $catID,
            'paged' => $paged
          );
          $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
         /*END QUERY*/
        ?>

        <div id="blogpost-list" class="container">
          <div class="row blogpost-wrapper">
            <?php
            /* Start the Loop */
            $i = 1;
            while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
              <?php if ($i % 3 == 0): ?>
                <div class="blogpost-item-grid">
                    <!-- some stuff to display the post.. doesn't really matter-->
                  <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-post-preview-large' ); ?>
                </div>
              <?php else: ?>
                <div class="blogpost-item-grid">
                    <!-- some stuff to display the post doesn't really matter -->
                  <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-post-preview' ); ?>
                </div>
              <?php endif; ?>
              <?php $i++; ?>
            <?php endwhile;?>
          </div>
        </div>

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/pagination' ); ?>

        <?php
        else :
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
        endif; ?>

<?php
get_footer();
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks. So at the end I just needed to get the category and add that to my quwìery 'cat' => $catID. Do you recommend to use the category page instead of the archive?

Comment: You can use it inside archive.php but check if is category first to give the correct parameter to your query. if it confuses  you just leave the category.php.

Comment: Ok gotcha. Thanks a lot for your help. I'm gonna use the category page it's more clean.Now the pagination it's not working: when I click to the next page I don't get the posts. I see the 404 page template instead. (I use the same code for displaying all the news and in that case works fine).

Comment: Pagination dsnt work in category ?? refresh your permalinks and check if something else breaks your pagination. maybe your pagination code

Comment: Yes it's not working only in the category page, I've tried to refresh the permalink without any luck. I'm using the default paginate_links() functions. I'll check that. thanks a lot https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Comment: No problem. try this Go to admin Dashboard then Settings->Reading then set Blog pages show at most is equal to you query posts_per_page. So in your query if you set posts_per_page => 6 then Blog pages show at most will be 6 . Just  a help for debug ! Have fun